# LaTeX file with KOMA-Script classes doesn't compile

Tags: xetex, pdftex, koma-script

I tried to compile my LaTeX file using KOMA-Script classes with different drivers (plain/PDF/Xe-LaTeX) but, unfortunately, didn't succeed. The package was installed under Windows 10 via MiKTeX package management tool and also manually by unzipping the latest version of KOMA 3.34 (koma-script.tds.zip) and running the texhash/mktexlsr commands
Here is my MWE:

```
    \documentclass{scrbook}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Chapter}
    \section{Section}
    \subsection{Subsection}
    
    \end{document}
```

And this is what I get if compiling the tex-file with `xelatex myfile.tex`:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.611 \FamilyProcessOptions{KOMA}
                                 \relax
?
)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\tocbasic.sty")
! Undefined control sequence.
l.176 \IfLTXAtLeastTF{2020/10/01}{\NewHook
                                          {\KOMAClassName/appendix}}{}
?
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\scrsize11pt.clo")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\typearea.sty")
! Undefined control sequence.
l.2635   \AddToHook
                   {selectfont}{\par@update}%
?
! Undefined control sequence.
\par@update ...par@update \fi \par@updaterelative

l.2635   \AddToHook{selectfont}{\par@update
                                           }%
```

Also I tried to change the encoding system of the source file (ANSI, UTF8 and UTF8-BOM) but in vain!

Comment: Looks like an update gone wrong. When MikTeX is involved (I've no direct experience with it) there is always the problem of refreshing the database both in user and admin mode.

Comment: @campa I added the package as an admin and ensured to refresh the file name database

Comment: It compiles for me (Tex Live 2021), so your code is not the issue.

Comment: @Ingmar, yes I know I've just tried it through overleaf and it works!

Comment: So it's an issue with your setup / MikTeX :-( not sure what to advise except to be fully updated and synchronized …

Comment: @Ingmar Sorry but fully updating MikTeX is not an option for me since different commercial type-1 PS fonts should be reinstalled which is time-consuming!

Comment: your latex format is too old (\AddToHook is undefined)  you should be able to tell miktex to build the latest formats but I have no experience of miktex

Comment: I am sorry to hear that. It's not an issue with either KOMA script or XeTeX, though. As you are at least 10 releases behind you're bound to run into all sort of issues in the future.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I am using the 2018 version of MikTeX 2.9 bundled with MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.6642 (1.40.19) and MiKTeX-XeTeX 2.9.6634 (0.99999)

Comment: @Ingmar, Is there a possibility to get old tds versions of KOMA?

Comment: the version of pdftex doesn't matter here, it is which version of latex you are running. You did not show that information (it is in the log) but  the code you show seems to be in error `l.176 \IfLTXAtLeastTF{2020/10/01}{\NewHook` is trying to only use `\NewHook` in new releases but it then used `\NewHook` in a latex where it is not defined.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle here is the log file: https://filebin.net/43a97bdxva9a496g

Comment: no sorry Im not downloading external links, latex shows a date at the start of every run, a current release will be  `LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1` what is yours?

Comment: No problem I understand. `This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (MiKTeX 2.9.6630 64-bit) (preloaded format=xelatex 2018.7.9)  19 AUG 2021 09:17
entering extended mode
**./cttest2.tex
(cttest2.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>`

Comment: you can find older releases of KOMA here https://sourceforge.net/projects/koma-script/files/KOMA-Script/. But your code snippet looks as if the test in koma for the format goes  wrong.

Comment: but I don't understand why reinstalling the fonts should be time consuming. If you did it correctly (by putting them in local texmf) you would only need to attach the tree and run updmap once. You could even try it with texlive 2021 first, if you don't want to change your miktex installation directly.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you for the suggestion! But excuse me what do you mean by the test in koma for the format goes wrong?

Comment: You have a very old xelatex release (2017) the code fragment shown in the error message is from a new koma release (why did you not keep the 2017 version?)  which appears to be testing the version date and only using new code in new releases but the test appears to be wrong and it is taking the "new" branch on your system.

Comment: `\IfLTXAtLeastTF{2020/10/01}` clearly means "if latex format newer than 2020-10-01" and if your format is older it shouldn't execute the \NewHook part. But it could be an side effect of a previous error, so don't put too much importance in it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, when I have installed MikTeX for the first time I didn't install KOMA at all. but now when I am urged to write my phd dissertation I am faced with this problem

Comment: It makes no sense to try to backdate everything to 2017, if you are starting your thesis, start with a current system.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I have a lot of figures done in PGF/TikZ and PSfrag and I hope that will not run into compatibility problems!